# jqgrid - cell is not hiding overflowing text

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using jqgrid plugin 4.6.0. The cell is not hiding the overflowing text either during normal display or during column resize. Please see the image below,

[image]

This issue is not occurring with jqgrid 4.5.2. Is there any setting available in latest version of plugin to avoid cell data wrapping?

Note: Header column is working as expected. The Actual text was 'Created On' and upon resize, it is hiding the overflow text.

Here is the CSS in IE Debugger mode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to verify why [the CSS rule](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L38) will be overwrite in your environment

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: pre; /* this one */
    height: 22px;     /* and this one */
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: inherit;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

I suppose that you have conflicts with some other CSS which you included on the HTML page.

Comment: CSS seems to be the same. I just attached the screenshot of above mentioned CSS from IE debugger in the question section. Please verify.

Comment: @Vim: Could you provide the demo which reproduces the problem? If I use jqGrid 4.6 I don't have any problems. Try for example [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleNavGrid3.htm). If you reduce the size of Date column the text will be cut. If you open Developer Tools and uncheck `white-space: pre;` in the rule `.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td` you will see immediately that the text in the cell will be wrapped like in the picture which you posted. In any way the original CSS of jqGrid should have no problems.

Comment: unfortunately I will not be able to provide you demo today. The behavior I mentioned still exists. I will try to provide you either demo or more details sooner.